# Gnosis Safe Fantom - Connect to site that needs to connect using MetaMask and not WalletConnect

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, fantom

have a multi-sig wallet created and in use. It requires 2 of 4 signatures and all seems to be working just fine with it.

I now need to interact with a website (https://play.tankwars.zone/) to connect the wallet with it, but the site only has MetaMask as an option and not WalletConnect.

Is there a way to make the two connect? Possibly using an app on the multi-sig contract, or some way to add it into a MetaMask account list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only 2 solutions I can think of:

- Ask them to implement WalletConnect.
- Create a `safe-app` for that application.

Comment: Can you create a safe-app even if I don't have any access the the source webpage?

Comment: no, app developers have to enable that

Comment: OK, this means it's currently not possible if you are not part of the dev team.